# Remove high residual and high leverage points in Influence Plot?

Tags: python, plot, regression, linear-regression, outliers

I'm using the Boston Housing Price data to do some linear regression.

Looking at the [Influence Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OumvO.png), there are a number of high residual points and a few high leverage points.

How do I remove the high residuals and high leverage points so I can re-run the linear regression model and re-plot the Influence and Q-Q plots?

---

Input:

```
m = ols('PRICE ~ CRIM + RM + PTRATIO',bos).fit()
print(m.summary())
```

Truncated Output:

```
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
Intercept     -3.3066      4.038     -0.819      0.413     -11.240       4.627
CRIM          -0.2021      0.032     -6.301      0.000      -0.265      -0.139
RM             7.3816      0.402     18.360      0.000       6.592       8.171
PTRATIO       -1.0742      0.133     -8.081      0.000      -1.335      -0.813
```

Influence Plot:

[image: Influence Plot]

QQ Plot:

[image: QQ Plot]

Answer (score 0):

In case of Studentized Residual, there is rule of thumb to flag an observation as a possible outlier:

```
Studentized Residual value for any observation > |3|
```

You can easily find those observations using the `statsmodels` library.
Here is a code that could help you find those observation for which studentized Residual value for any observation > |3|

```
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import OLSInfluence as olsi
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

lrmodel = OLS(y_train, x_train)
results = lrmodel.fit()

studentized_residuals = olsi(results).resid_studentized
keep_observ_at_indx = [i for i in studentized_residuals if abs(i) > 3] # applying the above mentioned thumb rule
leverage_pts = olsi(results).hat_matrix_diag        # this will give the array of leverage values
sb.residplot(x = studentized_residuals, y = leverage_pts, color = 'brown')
plt.show()
```

a.) Now, we finally have those index which are having studentized_residuals > 3, with these indices fetch the observations.

b.) As far as I have read from the internet, I think Cook's Distance is what will help us in the removal of the high-leverage points. But I am not sure how large is 'too large'! So cannot much comment on it. Below is the way you can compute the 'Cook's Distance'

```
cook_dist = dict(olsi(result).cooks_distance[0])

# {key(index) : value(cook's distance)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import OLSInfluence

model = sm.ols('y ~ x', data=df) # df is the data with columns x, y
model = model.fit()

studentized_residuals = OLSInfluence(model).summary_frame().student_resid
leverage = OLSInfluence(model).summary_frame().hat_diag

studentized_residual_threshold = 3
p = 2             # p is the number of model parameters including the intercept
n = df.shape[0]   # n is the number of observations
leverage_threshold = 3 * (p/n)
outlier_index = list(set(list(studentized_residuals[abs(studentized_residuals) > studentized_residual_threshold].index) + list(leverage[leverage > leverage_threshold].index))) 

# remove the outliers
df.drop(index=outlier_index, inplace=True)
```